# Img changes position of the parent div

Tags: html, css

I'm working on the main page of my website and want to display different kinds of square shape modules. Everything works fine until I use images on the modules. Whenever I add an img, the parent div changes position a few pixels down.

Here's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="module-box">
  <div class="module-dummy"></div>
  <div class="module-body">
    <a href="@post.linkToVideo">
      <div class="play-button-div">
        <img src=@Umbraco.Media(post.image).Url width="100%" height="100%" />
        <span class="play-button-icon"><i class="fa fa-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.module-box {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.module-dummy {
    margin-top: 100%;
}

.module-body {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.play-button-div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}

.play-button-div img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}

.play-button-div i{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #0080ff;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50px;
      border: 3px solid #0080ff;
    font-size: 70px;
   text-align: center;
    line-height:100px;
    text-indent:15px;
    opacity: .8;

}
.play-button-icon {

    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:auto;
}

.play-button-div:hover img {
  opacity: .6;
}

.play-button-div:hover i {
    background-color: #0080ff;
    color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #FFF;
}
```

Comment: we need more info to help you, since we can't reproduce the problem

Comment: why don't you give height to img tag as per the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that the parent DIV becomes a little bit higher / pushes subsequent elements down by adding a little space below the image? In this case, you can add `line-height: 0` to the image container (but only if there is *no* text in it).

On the other hand, if this is the CSS for your containers and images:

```
.play-button-div {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display:table;
    position:relative;
}
.play-button-div img {
    display:block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position:relative;
}
```

, then you should change `display:block;` to `display:table-cell;` in `.play-button-div img`, and also add `vertical-align: top;` to it.